# Do I need an STA thread to use WPF controls that won't be shown?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm creating an image by putting WPF controls on a Grid and then saving it to a file. I'm never showing the Grid. It works fine.

But when I try to put it in a `Task` and `Task.Run` it, it fails with:

> The calling thread must be STA because many UI components require this

Since I'm never showing the Grid, is it perhaps possible in some simple manner to circumvent this error, without having to create a separate Thread for the Task? And I can't have it on the real UI thread, that's a requirement here.

(I'm asking if there's a way to run this ***without*** an STA thread.)

Answer (score 1):

WPF itself is not safe for multithreading except in very particular and documented classes.  WPF is only usable from an STA thread with a dispatcher pumping messages.  You can have more than one STA thread and dispatcher per process, though.

For example, you might have one or more background threads which only render images.  Each you would start by marking `Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`, create a dispatcher by accessing `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` on the background thread, and pump messages with `Dispatcher.Run()`.  Work can be marshalled with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and the thread can be ended by calling `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()`.

As an example, here's a demo creating two STA threads with windows shown on each, and the ability to invoke new work on the "background" thread:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;

internal static class Program
{
    private static Dispatcher BackgroundDispatcher;

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thread2 = new Thread(thread2_Main);
        thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread2.Start();

        var app = new Application();
        var window1 = new Window() { Title = "Main Thread" };
        window1.MouseDoubleClick += btOpenNewBackgroundWindow_Click;
        app.Run(window1);

        thread2.Join();
    }

    private static void thread2_Main(object? obj)
    {
        BackgroundDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        var window2 = new Window() { Title = "Background Thread" };
        window2.Show();
        window2.Closed += (sender, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        Dispatcher.Run();
    }

    private static void btOpenNewBackgroundWindow_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var bgDisp = BackgroundDispatcher;
        bgDisp.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var addl = new Window() { Title = "Background Thread invoked from Foreground" };
            addl.Show();
        });
    }
}
```